# How to return Row and Col using Grid in Go Fyne?

Tags: go, fyne

I am having a hard time figuring out how to return the rows and cols of the grid when the button is pressed. Here I have a simple code in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Grid")
    content := container.NewGridWithColumns(3)
    for y := 0; y < 3; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < 3; x++ {
            btn := widget.NewButton("", nil) // returns row and col of the grid
            content.Add(btn)
        }
    }
    w.SetContent(content)
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

I hope you guys can help :)

Answer (score 0):

As the function is defined inline you can simply capture the variables.

```
    for y := 0; y < 3; y++ {
        savedY := y
        for x := 0; x < 3; x++ {
            savedX := x
            btn := widget.NewButton("", 
                func() {
                    log.PrintLn(“Saved”, savedX, savedY)
                })
            content.Add(btn)
        }
    }
```